# Line Feed or Carriage Return - What to use?

Tags: javascript

> In javascript, Line Feed and Carriage Return behaves similarly.

Which one to use and when?

OR

Can it be used alternatively?

#### Unicode Characters:

```
Line Feed: \u000A

Carriage Return: \u000D
```

#### Code:

```
<script>
    alert("Hello \u000A World - <LF>");
    alert("Hello \u000D World - <CR>");
</script>
```

Comment: While not exactly an answer to your Question, the newline (\n) is preferable, at least in your example (and probably elsewhere as well).

Comment: @AKTed could you explain why i should prefer newline (\n) more than line feed (\r) ?

Comment: I shouldn't have said *preferable* since that implies a standard. It is really a lazy way to code. See [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style#answer-5757349) for why you should really use both: `/r/n`.

Comment: @AKTed: That question and answer is about the HTTP protocol. If you're writing an HTTP client in JavaScript, then, sure, you should use `\r\n`, but that's a very specific context. In the context of an alert box and most other scenarios where you just want to create a new line, all you need is `\n` ("newline"). There's no real reason to use a carriage return. There's no carriage or cursor to return or an arbitrary specification/outdated tradition that requires it.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: You're right...I jumped the gun on that. I stand corrected. +1 for the "writing an HTTP client in JavaScript" reference. :)

Comment: @AKTed I just need that for javascript alert box. And i suppose we can't write the "\n" (newline) character to write a newline. It would be good to just give the unicode version of the newline character. But i didn't find any.

So.. d question arises to either use the line feed character (\u000A) or the carriage return character (\u000D) to get a new line. But which one is preferable or better & why?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté reply d above comment^

Comment: You *can* write "\n" in an alert. `alert("hello" + "\n" + "world")` or simply `alert("hello\nworld")`. As far as I know, that's valid in all browsers. I can't say which is better, but that's the way I've usually seen/done it.